# Como pegar informações do sistema operacional do cliente?

Tags: php, sistema-operacional

Preciso pegar informações do sistema operacional de quem acessou a página, por exemplo, através de um comando descobrir se é Windows, MAC, Linux.

Comment: Do sistema operacional do computador da pessoa que está acessando o meu site

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis Tá claro na pergunta "_de quem acessou a página_". :)

Answer (score 8):

Existe alguns métodos, mas nenhum 100% garantido, como mencionado na resposta do Anderson.

Os dados relativos ao `USER_AGENT` serão obtidos através da variável de ambiente `HTTP_USER_AGENT`:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
//Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
--------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^SO^^^^^^^^^^^^^
?>
```

Pode extrair apenas o `SO` com uma regex.

```
<?php
preg_match('((?<=\().*?(?=;))',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$matches);
echo $matches[0];
//Windows NT 6.1
?>
```

Ou usando a função [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php):

```
<?php
$browser = get_browser();
echo $browser->platform;
//Win7
?>
```

Como observado pelo @AndersonCarlosWoss a função `get_browser()` é dependente da 
diretiva `[browscap]` do `php.ini` que por padrão vem desabilitada, então faz-se necessário habilitá-la:

```
[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
browscap="\xampp\php\extras\php_browscap.ini"//este caminho é relativo para cada instalação
```

Onde `php_browscap.ini` é a base de dados mantida pela [browscap.org](http://browscap.org/).

Answer (score 8):

**Primeiro, não há como obter esta informação com certeza absoluta, pois toda e qualquer informação do cliente passada ao servidor será através da requisição HTTP e, portanto, pode ser modificada manualmente. Ou seja, você pode utilizar tal informação, mas não pode confiar nela.**

Esse tipo de informação é passado ao servidor via requisição HTTP, mais exatamente através do cabeçalho `User-Agent`, que, no PHP, poderá ser acessado como: `$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]`. O valor deste cabeçalho será algo como:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36 OPR/46.0.2597.57
```

Onde leia-se:

- `Mozilla`: Indica que o *user agent* é baseado no Mozilla, o que é válido para os navegadores Gecko, como Firefox e Netscape. Para os outros navegadores, indica que é compatível com o Mozilla, mas no geral, esta informação só está presente por questões históricas;
- `5.0`: Versão do Mozilla;
- `Windows NT 10.0`: informação do sistema operacional (essa é a que te interessa, aparentemente);
- `Win64`: Indica que o cliente utiliza a API Win32 para Windows 64-bits;
- `x64`: Arquitetura 64-bits do Windows;
- `AppleWebKit`: WebKit utilizado;
- `537.36`: Build utilizada do WebKit;
- `KHTML`: Motor de layout open source pelo projeto KDE;
- `like Gecko`: *Sem informações conclusivas*;
- `Chrome`: Nome do navegador utilizado;
- `59.0.3071.115`: Versão do Chrome;
- `Safari`: Indica que é baseado no Safari;
- `537.36`: Build do Safari utilizado;
- `OPR`: *Sem informações conclusivas*;
- `46.0.2597.57`: *Sem informações conclusivas*;

> Exemplo retirado de http://www.useragentstring.com.

Muitas dessas informações você pode obter diretamente no site supracitado:

*List of User Agent Strings*: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

E até utilizar a [API](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/api.php) fornecida por eles:

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.useragentstring.com/?uas=%s&getJSON=all";
$url = sprintf($url, urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($output);

echo "Seu sistema operacional é:", $data->os_type;
```

Ou utilizando expressões regulares para obter os dados, mas não sei se funcionaria em todos os casos (i.e. sempre o cabeçalho segue o mesmo padrão), portanto, as soluções mais fáceis são a apresentada pelo [MagicHat](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/227235/5878) e provavelmente as bibliotecas apresentadas pelo [Guilherme](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/227298/5878).

---

Leituras interessantes:

- [Understanding the user-agent string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(VS.85).aspx)
- [Firefox user agent string reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent/Firefox)

Comment: Lá vem show ;)!

Answer (score 4):

Código postado em um post no link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070154/get-operating-system-info-with-php

Retorna inclusive o navegador:

```
<?php

$user_agent     =   $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

function getOS() { 

    global $user_agent;

    $os_platform    =   "Unknown OS Platform";

    $os_array       =   array(
                            '/windows nt 10/i'     =>  'Windows 10',
                            '/windows nt 6.3/i'     =>  'Windows 8.1',
                            '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8',
                            '/windows nt 6.1/i'     =>  'Windows 7',
                            '/windows nt 6.0/i'     =>  'Windows Vista',
                            '/windows nt 5.2/i'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
                            '/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'Windows XP',
                            '/windows xp/i'         =>  'Windows XP',
                            '/windows nt 5.0/i'     =>  'Windows 2000',
                            '/windows me/i'         =>  'Windows ME',
                            '/win98/i'              =>  'Windows 98',
                            '/win95/i'              =>  'Windows 95',
                            '/win16/i'              =>  'Windows 3.11',
                            '/macintosh|mac os x/i' =>  'Mac OS X',
                            '/mac_powerpc/i'        =>  'Mac OS 9',
                            '/linux/i'              =>  'Linux',
                            '/ubuntu/i'             =>  'Ubuntu',
                            '/iphone/i'             =>  'iPhone',
                            '/ipod/i'               =>  'iPod',
                            '/ipad/i'               =>  'iPad',
                            '/android/i'            =>  'Android',
                            '/blackberry/i'         =>  'BlackBerry',
                            '/webos/i'              =>  'Mobile'
                        );

    foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value) { 

        if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
            $os_platform    =   $value;
        }

    }   

    return $os_platform;

}

function getBrowser() {

    global $user_agent;

    $browser        =   "Unknown Browser";

    $browser_array  =   array(
                            '/msie/i'       =>  'Internet Explorer',
                            '/firefox/i'    =>  'Firefox',
                            '/safari/i'     =>  'Safari',
                            '/chrome/i'     =>  'Chrome',
                            '/edge/i'       =>  'Edge',
                            '/opera/i'      =>  'Opera',
                            '/netscape/i'   =>  'Netscape',
                            '/maxthon/i'    =>  'Maxthon',
                            '/konqueror/i'  =>  'Konqueror',
                            '/mobile/i'     =>  'Handheld Browser'
                        );

    foreach ($browser_array as $regex => $value) { 

        if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
            $browser    =   $value;
        }

    }

    return $browser;

}


$user_os        =   getOS();
$user_browser   =   getBrowser();

$device_details =   "<strong>Browser: </strong>".$user_browser."<br /><strong>Operating System: </strong>".$user_os."";

print_r($device_details);

echo("<br /><br /><br />".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."");

?>
```

Comment: Qual a necessidade do `global`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Apenas postei o código de outra postagem no site em inglês. Qualquer dúvida você pode perguntar ao autor do código acessando o link informado na resposta.

Comment: Não quer dizer que você não possa fazer uma revisão/melhorar e até se aprimorar ;)

Answer (score 3):

Como já foi dito na resposta do Anderson, não é possivel detectar de maneira garantida, porque o cabeçalho HTTP chamado `User-Agent` pode ser alterado e assim enganaria o script, criar um regex único também não é algo fácil e pode não ser tão assertivo (apesar de talvez ser o melhor dos caminhos).

A solução do MagicHat exige as vezes o `browsercap.ini` ou atualizações no mesmo que podem não ser fáceis de efetuar em servidores de produção, ou seja você pode até conseguir fazer isto bem em um servidor local ou o qual tem acesso de administrador, mas para muitos servidores isto não será possivel.

**Para facilitar** existem 3 libs que podem ser interessantes, pois não requerem serviços externos e nem acesso administrativo ao servidor, a única coisa que é necessário é o `composer` para instalação:

## Browser Detector

Para instalar, na pasta do teu projeto via terminal ou cmd digite:

```
composer require sinergi/browser-detector
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Sinergi\BrowserDetector\Os;

$os = new Os();

var_dump($os->getName());
```

Além de detectar o navegador e o idioma

Mais detalhes em: https://github.com/sinergi/php-browser-detector

## DeviceDetector

Tem sistema de cache, detecta BOTs e mais uma série de opções, para instalar na pasta do teu projeto via terminal ou cmd digite:

```
composer require piwik/device-detector
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use DeviceDetector\DeviceDetector;

$dd = new DeviceDetector($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

$dd->parse();

$osData = $dd->getOs();

var_dump($osData->name);
```

mais detalhes em https://github.com/piwik/device-detector

## Agent

Agent é um lib como suporte para Laravel simples de usar que também detecta se é BOT, mobile ou Desktop, para instalar na pasta do teu projeto via terminal ou cmd digite:

```
composer require jenssegers/agent
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Jenssegers\Agent\Agent;

$agent = new Agent();

var_dump($agent->platform());
```

Mais detalhes em https://github.com/jenssegers/agent

---

### Com RegEx

O código na resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/18070424/1518921 (mesma fonte que o David usou em sua resposta) esta um **pouco "obsoleto"**,  e é possivel fazer melhoras simples, por exemplo:

1. Quando encontrar o sistema pode-se usar `break` ou `return` dentro do `foreach` assim deixando um pouco mais rapido a resposta (micro-otimização).
2. Para diminuir um pouco o código é colocar os **"delimitadores"** dentro do `preg_match` assim não precisaria escrever `/..../i` para cada item.
3. O uso de `global` simplesmente não faz muito sentido, fora que deixar a variável `$user_agent` no escopo "global" pode causar acidentes no script.

O código revisado ficaria assim:

```
<?php

function getOS() {
    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    $os_array = array(
        'windows nt 10'      =>  'Windows 10',
        'windows nt 6\.3'     =>  'Windows 8.1',
        'windows nt 6\.2'     =>  'Windows 8',
        'windows nt 6\.1'     =>  'Windows 7',
        'windows nt 6\.0'     =>  'Windows Vista',
        'windows nt 5\.2'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
        'windows nt 5\.1'     =>  'Windows XP',
        'windows xp'         =>  'Windows XP',
        'windows nt 5\.0'     =>  'Windows 2000',
        'windows me'         =>  'Windows ME',
        'win98'              =>  'Windows 98',
        'win95'              =>  'Windows 95',
        'win16'              =>  'Windows 3.11',
        'macintosh|mac os x' =>  'Mac OS X',
        'mac_powerpc'        =>  'Mac OS 9',
        'linux'              =>  'Linux',
        'ubuntu'             =>  'Ubuntu',
        'iphone'             =>  'iPhone',
        'ipod'               =>  'iPod',
        'ipad'               =>  'iPad',
        'android'            =>  'Android',
        'blackberry'         =>  'BlackBerry',
        'webos'              =>  'Mobile'
    );

    foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value) {
        if (preg_match('/' . $regex . '/i', $user_agent)) {
            return $value;
        }
    }

    return 'Unknown OS Platform';
}

function getBrowser() {
    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    $browser_array = array(
        'msie'       =>  'Internet Explorer',
        'firefox'    =>  'Firefox',
        'safari'     =>  'Safari',
        'chrome'     =>  'Chrome',
        'edge'       =>  'Edge',
        'opera'      =>  'Opera',
        'netscape'   =>  'Netscape',
        'maxthon'    =>  'Maxthon',
        'konqueror'  =>  'Konqueror',
        'mobile'     =>  'Handheld Browser'
    );

    foreach ($browser_array as $regex => $value) {
        if (preg_match('/' . $regex . '/i', $user_agent)) {
            return $value;
        }
    }

    return 'Unknown Browser';
}

echo 'Sistema operacional: ', getOS(), PHP_EOL;
echo 'Navegador: ', getBrowser(), PHP_EOL;
echo 'User-Agent: ', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], PHP_EOL;
```