# Pegar dados do usuário visitante com php

Tags: php

estou montando um sistema de suporte e preciso pegar alguns dados do cliente quando o mesmo abre o atendimento
estes dados são:
IP
Sistema Operacional neste formato ( Windows 10 64x por ex )
Navegador utilizado ( Google Chrome Versao 99 )

o ip eu consigo pegar normalmente. o que falta é o resto e o mais próximo que cheguei foi isto aqui;

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$bname = 'Unknown';
$platform = 'Unknown';
$version= "";

if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'Linux';
}
elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'Mac';
}
elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'Windows';
}


if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
    $ub = "MSIE";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
    $ub = "Firefox";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Google Chrome';
    $ub = "Chrome";
}
elseif(preg_match('/AppleWebKit/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'AppleWebKit';
    $ub = "Opera";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Apple Safari';
    $ub = "Safari";
}

elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Netscape';
    $ub = "Netscape";
}

$known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
$pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
}


$i = count($matches['browser']);
if ($i != 1) {
    if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }
    else {
        $version= $matches['version'][1];
    }
}
else {
    $version= $matches['version'][0];
}

// check if we have a number
if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

$Browser = array(
        'userAgent' => $u_agent,
        'name'      => $bname,
        'version'   => $version,
        'platform'  => $platform,
        'pattern'    => $pattern
);

$navegador = "Navegador: " . $Browser['name'] . " " . $Browser['version'];
$so = "SO: " . $Browser['platform'];

echo $navegador . "<br> $so";
```

e isto retorna

> Navegador: Google Chrome 60.0.3112.90
>   SO: Windows

por tanto apenas falta trazer qual sistema windows é no caso se for windows ou qual linux ou outro sistema operacional que for e se disponível se é 32 ou 64x

alguém poderia me orientar com alterar esta função para exibir pelo menos a versão do OS?

Comment: Relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227228/como-pegar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-sistema-operacional-do-cliente/227235#227235

Comment: Qual seria a saída que deseja?

Comment: unica coisa que falta é qual versão de windows por ex windows 10 ou 8.1 ou se for mac ou liux qual versão que é por ex Centos 7 ou Snow Leopard e etc

Comment: @MagicHat não é duplicata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes criar um array com os SO e verificar na variavel `$user_agent` - cujo valor é dado por `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` - com um `foreach`

```
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

function getOS() { 

   global $user_agent;

   $os_platform  =  "SO desconhecido";

   $os_array  =  array(
                        '/windows nt 10/i'     =>  'Windows 10',
                        '/windows nt 6.3/i'     =>  'Windows 8.1',
                        '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8',
                        '/windows nt 6.1/i'     =>  'Windows 7',
                        '/windows nt 6.0/i'     =>  'Windows Vista',
                        '/windows nt 5.2/i'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
                        '/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'Windows XP',
                        '/windows xp/i'         =>  'Windows XP',
                        '/windows nt 5.0/i'     =>  'Windows 2000',
                        '/windows me/i'         =>  'Windows ME',
                        '/win98/i'              =>  'Windows 98',
                        '/win95/i'              =>  'Windows 95',
                        '/win16/i'              =>  'Windows 3.11',
                        '/macintosh|mac os x/i' =>  'Mac OS X',
                        '/mac_powerpc/i'        =>  'Mac OS 9',
                        '/linux/i'              =>  'Linux',
                        '/ubuntu/i'             =>  'Ubuntu',
                        '/iphone/i'             =>  'iPhone',
                        '/ipod/i'               =>  'iPod',
                        '/ipad/i'               =>  'iPad',
                        '/android/i'            =>  'Android',
                        '/blackberry/i'         =>  'BlackBerry',
                        '/webos/i'              =>  'Mobile'
                    );

   foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value) { 

       if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
          $os_platform    =   $value;
       }

   }   

return $os_platform;

}

$user_os = getOS();

echo "<strong>Sistema Operacional: </strong>".$user_os;
```

[**Fonte - Stack Exchange**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6077/browser-and-os-detection-script)